# How to get a classification problem using the surprise library?

Tags: python, regression, classification, cross-validation, recommendation-engine

How can I get this to be a classification problem? I have that users have rated a restaurant either 1,2 or 3. I just want to know how to indicate the suprise library's reader method that I want it to be a classification problem. Here is the code:

```
reader = Reader(rating_scale=(1,3))
rating_data = Dataset.load_from_df(userrating[['userID', 'placeID', 'rating']], reader)
KNN = KNNWithMeans(verbose=True, n_epochs=100)
KNN_results = cross_validate(KNN, rating_data, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE', 'fcp'], cv=3, verbose=True)
```

It is currently a regression problem, hence why I use RMSE and MAE as metrics but after transforming it to a classification problem, I would like to test the accuracy and the precision